# Printing from ppt VBA to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to convert excel VBA to ppt VBA. The original excel VBA (in "Comparison.xlsm") compared values from other excel workbooks and printed mismatching ones in Comparison.xlsm's Sheet1.

I know my code below (which is my ppt VBA version) is seeing the correct workbooks because when I use MsgBox to print values, I get the correct ones. However, my issue is when I try to print the incorrect values into Comparison.xlsm's Sheet1 at:

```
mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & nextCell).Value = ID_ISS
mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextCell).Value = "Symbol"
mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextCell).Value = "(FCST)"
```

I just don't see it print in the excel spreadsheet. Here's the relevant code:

EDIT: I changed it to add all my code -

```
Dim strIDRangeISS As String
Dim strIDRangeFCST As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim ID_ISS As Long
Dim ID_FCST As Long
Dim nextCell As Integer
Dim iRowISS As Integer
Dim iRowFCST As Integer

Dim wbkFCST As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbkISS As Excel.Workbook
Dim mainWB As Excel.Workbook  
Dim varSheetFCST As Excel.Worksheet
Dim varSheetISS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim mainWS As Excel.Worksheet

nextCell = 1

Set wbkFCST = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Documents\FCST.xlsx")
Set varSheetFCST = wbkFCST.Worksheets("Details")

Set wbkISS = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\...\Documents\ISS.xlsm")
Set varSheetISS = wbkISS.Worksheets("ISS")

Set mainWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\...\Documents\Comparison.xlsm")
Set mainWS = mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

strIDRangeISS = "A2:D50" 
strIDRangeFCST = "B2:I50"

'varSheetISS = varSheetISS.Range(strIDRangeISS)
'varSheetFCST = varSheetFCST.Range(strIDRangeFCST)
Dim ISSArray As Variant: ISSArray = varSheetISS.Range(strIDRangeISS)
Dim FCSTArray As Variant: FCSTArray = varSheetFCST.Range(strIDRangeFCST)

For iRowISS = LBound(ISSArray, 1) To UBound(ISSArray, 1)    'Goes down ISS' ID column
    ID_ISS = ISSArray(iRowISS, 1)
    MsgBox ("ID_ISS is " & ID_ISS)      

    For iRowFCST = LBound(FCSTArray, 1) To UBound(FCSTArray, 1)    'Goes down FCST ID column
        ID_FCST = FCSTArray(iRowFCST, 1)
        MsgBox ("ID_FCST is " & ID_FCST)       

        'Compares ISS ID to FCST ID till finds matching
        If (ID_ISS = ID_FCST) Then
            'If corr symbols aren't same, record ID in Comparison's spreadsheet and go onto next ISS ID
            If (ISSArray(iRowISS, 3) <> FCSTArray(iRowFCST, 2)) Or (ISSArray(iRowISS, 4) <> FCSTArray(iRowFCST, 8)) Then
                mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & nextCell).Value = ID_ISS

                'Symbol mismatch
                If (ISSArray(iRowISS, 3) <> FCSTArray(iRowFCST, 2)) Then
                    mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextCell).Value = "Symbol"
                End If

                '(FCST) mismatch
                If (ISSArray(iRowISS, 4) <> FCSTArray(iRowFCST, 8)) Then
                    mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextCell).Value = "(FCST)"
                End If

                nextCell = nextCell + 1
            End If
            Exit For    'If corr symbols are same, go onto next ISS ID
        End If

        'Reached end of FCST ID's and no match -> record ISS ID
        If iRowFCST = 49 Then
            Workbooks("Comparison.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & nextCell).Value = ID_ISS
            Workbooks("Comparison.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextCell).Value = "No corressponding Issue ID"
            nextCell = nextCell + 1
            Exit For
        End If

    Next iRowFCST
Next iRowISS
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? E.g. what does this do?: If (ISSArray(iRowISS, 3) <> FCSTArray(iRowFCST, 2)) Then

Comment: What error do you get and are you sure `nextCell` has an integer value greater than 0?

Comment: @Absinthe I edited to have all the code

Comment: @PortlandRunner - What happens when you step through the code line by line (e.g. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)? Are you getting past your If statements?

Comment: @PortlandRunner Oops, sorry!

Comment: @user90823745 What happens when you step through the code line by line (e.g. cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)? Are you getting past your If statements?